# Can CMake FetchContent be tricked to download malicious tag instead of commit hash?

Tags: cmake

I'm using CMake's GIT_TAG option, which accepts either a tag name or a commit hash. Suppose an attacker gains access to the Git repository and adds a tag with a name that matches a trusted commit hash. Could this cause CMake to download the contents of the tag instead of the intended commit hash? If so, how can this be prevented?

Comment: "Could this cause CMake to download the contents of the tag instead of the intended commit hash?" - CMake just executes `git` with appropriate parameters. If `git` downloads the tag in that case, then CMake will get content of the tag. If you don't trust the repository, then do not use: e.g. use other repository, or download the content and ship it with your project. Protecting from an untrusted internet content is not a purpose of a tool which builds the project **from sources**. If you bother about safety, then distribute your software in binary form.